# Typeset URL in a non-typewriter font

Tags: fonts, urls

I use `\usepackage{url}` and `\url{…}` to typeset URLs, but the typewriter font stands out a little too much.  How can I have the URLs typeset in a different font?

Comment: May I suggest you leave your questions up for a short while before answering them yourself; there was a little discussion on this: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to the [README](http://www.utexas.edu/ogs/etd/LaTeX/Style.files/url.sty.readme.txt),

> you can switch the style of printing
>   using `\urlstyle{tt}`, where `tt` can
>   be any defined style.  The pre-defined
>   styles are `tt`, `rm`, `sf`, and
>   `same`, all of which produce the same
>   linebreaks but use different fonts—the
>   first three select a specific font and
>   the ‘same’ style uses the current text
>   font.

You can also define your own font:

```
\makeatletter
\def\url@foostyle{%
  \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\sf}}{\def\UrlFont{\small\ttfamily}}}
\makeatother

%% Now actually use the newly defined style.
\urlstyle{foo}
```

(The last example is from http://www.kronto.org/thesis/tips/url-formatting.html.)