# Special character in url link

Tags: hyperref, urls, links

I would like to insert the following text:

```
\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_successful_coups_d'état}{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List\_of\_successful\_coups\_d'état}
```

However, that doesn't work because of the special character é in the first entry. Is there any way to get it working? I am not using `\url` because I don't want it to be formatted. But if someone knows how to prevent `\url` from changing the font, that would solve the problem, too.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a minimmal example (ME) that includes the entire LaTeX source and that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If you've loaded `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, it should work without problems.

Comment: For your second question: [Typeset URL in a non-typewriter font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667/typeset-url-in-a-non-typewriter-font)

Comment: Use `%E9` instead of `é` in the first argument. This is called URL encoding.

Answer (score 2):

To summarise the suggestions in the comments, the following should all work if your file is saved with a UTF8 encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_successful_coups_d'état}{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List\_of\_successful\_coups\_d'état}

\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_successful_coups_d'\%E9tat}{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List\_of\_successful\_coups\_d'état}

\urlstyle{same}
\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_successful_coups_d'état}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Bad title
The requested page title contains an invalid UTF-8 sequence.