# Hyperref: Danish ø in `\url` or `\href` doesn't work (appears as \T1\)

Tags: hyperref, unicode, urls

Refer to [this question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87205/special-character-in-url-link).
When I compile the file below (encoded in utf-8) with `pdflatex`, only the middle option produces a working link as opposed to all three in the linked question. In addition, the third option doesn't display correctly. Is this a bug in hyperref? I can typeset the ø fine outside the `\url` command.

I would prefer to use the third option to typeset a link, as it handles linebreaking for me. Is there a workaround or am I doing something wrong?
Is there a way to make `\href` handle linebreaking like `\url` does?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{https://da.wikisource.org/wiki/Forsøg_over_den_electriske_Vexelkamps_Indvirkning_paa_Magnetnaalen}{https://da.wikisource.org/wiki/Forsøg\_over\_den\_electriske\_Vexelkamps\_Indvirkning\_paa\_Magnetnaalen}

\href{https://da.wikisource.org/wiki/Fors\%C3\%B8g_over_den_electriske_Vexelkamps_Indvirkning_paa_Magnetnaalen}{https://da.wikisource.org/wiki/Forsøg\_over\_den\_electriske\_Vexelkamps\_Indvirkning\_paa\_Magnetnaalen}

\urlstyle{same}
\url{https://da.wikisource.org/wiki/Forsøg_over_den_electriske_Vexelkamps_Indvirkning_paa_Magnetnaalen}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot of my pdf viewer (Adobe Reader):
[image: Screenshot in Adobe Reader]

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you use, and how recently did you update it? If I run your code on a MacTeX2015 (on a MacBook Pro running MacOSX 10.10.5), all three URL strings in the pdf file provide valid links to the wikipedia page.

Comment: The PDF format expects 7-bit ASCII for the URI. Therefore, the second, percent escaped version is correct.

Comment: My TeX distribution is TeX Live. My `pdflatex` version is
`pdflatex --version`
`pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX)
kpathsea version 6.2.0`.
I'll  update all my packages with TeX Live Manager and try again.

Comment: I updated and now my version is 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16. The output is exactly as before.

@HeikoOberdiek is there a way to use the percent escaped version of the url in the `\url`command while displaying the character ø? Or to make hyperref break between lines like `\url`?

Comment: @Pétur No, but there is `\href`, e.g. `\href{<URL, percent encoded>}{\nolinkurl{<URL>}}`.