# How can I define a command for urls using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, urls

I know I can use the package hyperref for urls, but I want is to create a definition that uses this and assigns a color, for example

```
\c{url}{Something}
```

would write `Something` in `crimson color` linked to the `url` (and assume default urls aren't in crimson)

Comment: what about `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=magenta]{hyperref}` and `\href{http://www.myurl.com}{something}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hyperref` options, and locally modify it when needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=magenta]{hyperref}

    \newcommand{\myhref}[2]
        {\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}%
         \href{#1}{#2}%
         \hypersetup{urlcolor=magenta}%
        }

\begin{document}
    Here is \href{http://www.myurl.com}{my link}.

    Here is \myhref{http://www.myurl.com}{my special link}.

    And here,  \href{http://www.myurl.com}{another normal link}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will break if the url contains special chars like % or #.

Comment: Cf. [Special character in url link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87205/special-character-in-url-link)