# biblatex: DOI with special characters leading to invalid URLs

Tags: urls, biblatex-chicago

This question is very similar to

[Special characters in DOI leading to invalid URLs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618777/special-characters-in-doi-leading-to-invalid-urls)

but the solution found in the above Q&A doesn't work with `biblatex-chicago`.

Specifically, I have to deal with DOIs with special characters: for example,

```
10.1175/1520-0485(1975)005<0300:CTWIAS>2.0.CO;2
```

But, the URL which directly corresponds to this DOI

```
https://doi.org/10.1175/1520-0485(1975)005<0300:CTWIAS>2.0.CO;2
```

includes invalid characters as a URL. How can one set things up so that such DOIs as this are correctly encoded when they are turned into URLs?

The solution found in the above Q&A was to use the `doi` package and

```
\doi{10.1175/1520-0485(1975)005<0300:CTWIAS>2.0.CO;2}
```

So, the solution was simple: Just `\usepackage{doi}`. This solution works in the traditional LaTeX + BibTeX way because bib styles tend to use the `\doi` macro.

As the following code demonstrates, however, this method doesn't work with `biblatex-chicago`. The hyperlinks it generates still contain invalid URLs, which some PDF viewers (like Mac's Preview) cannot handle. The code below also demonstrates that the `\doi` macro itself produces correctly encoded URLs. Apparently, `biblatex-chicago` doesn't use the `\doi` command.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[doi=only]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{doi}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{tmp.bib}
@article{ref-with-odd-doi,
  title = {Coastal Trapped Waves in a Stratified Ocean},
  author = {Allen, J. S.},
  year = {1975},
  journal = {J. Phys. Oceanogr.},
  volume = {5},
  pages = {300--325},
  doi = {10.1175/1520-0485(1975)005<0300:CTWIAS>2.0.CO;2}
}
@article{ref-with-nice-doi,
  title = {Something},
  author = {Some Author},
  year = {1975},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  volume = {5},
  pages = {300--325},
  doi = {10.1016/j.dsr.2003.09.011}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{tmp}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{ref-with-odd-doi}\\
\cite{ref-with-nice-doi}\\
\doi{10.1175/1520-0485(1975)005<0300:CTWIAS>2.0.CO;2}\\
\doi{10.1016/j.dsr.2003.09.011}\\
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: while it would be possible to postprocess the doi to make it safe it would probably make more sense if biber would percent encode it, and add a doiraw field similar to the way it handles url.

Answer (score 0):

Imho the best would be if biber would handle doi like url and percent encode them directly. But you can also replace the problematic chars:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[doi=only]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{doi}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \printdoi#1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl{#1}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn\l_tmpa_tl {<}{\c_percent_str3C}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn\l_tmpa_tl {>}{\c_percent_str3E}
  % expands with more if needed ...
  \href{\doiurl\l_tmpa_tl}{\nolinkurl{#1}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{\printdoi{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{tmp.bib}
@article{ref-with-odd-doi,
  title = {Coastal Trapped Waves in a Stratified Ocean},
  author = {Allen, J. S.},
  year = {1975},
  journal = {J. Phys. Oceanogr.},
  volume = {5},
  pages = {300--325},    
  doi = {10.1175/1520-0485(1975)005<0300:CTWIAS>2.0.CO;2}
}
@article{ref-with-nice-doi,
  title = {Something},
  author = {Some Author},
  year = {1975},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  volume = {5},
  pages = {300--325},
  doi = {10.1016/j.dsr.2003.09.011}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{tmp}
\begin{document}
%\noindent 
\cite{ref-with-odd-doi}\\
\cite{ref-with-nice-doi}

\doi{10.1175/1520-0485(1975)005<0300:CTWIAS>2.0.CO;2}\\
\doi{10.1175/1520-0485(1975)005<0300:CTWIAS>2.0.CO;2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```